# How to consider a list of parameters as input field in a macro?

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following macro:

```
%macro create_table(TableFields=,TimeS=);
...
WHERE T1.TIME_S = &TIMES.
%mend create_table;
```

I would like to be able to consider multiple Time as follows: `39 51 63 ...` in the input field, something like

```
%create_table(TableFields=id,TimeS=39 51 63);
```

unfortunately I am getting the following error message:

> ERROR: Teradata prepare: Syntax error: expected something between an
>   integer and the integer '51'. SQL statement was: SELECT

These values are included in  `WHERE T1.TIME_S = &TIMES.` with 
TIMES defined as an interval: `do i=&time_s_lower. to &time_s_upper.`;
Is it possible to list these values? If yes, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to pass in an array of values using a `JSON` or `ARRAY` data type and then include that in your `WHERE` clause.  Here's an example for `ARRAY` with `UNNEST`: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/edz49eg9DZMoHxqr9Fn2WQ

Comment: When working with macro, it's often easiest to start with working SAS code (no macro), and then work on a macro that will generate that code.  From the error message, it's not clear if your macro is generating SAS data step code,  PROC SQL code, or a Teradata query (explicit pass-through).  Do you have working SAS code? If so, please post that code.  That will make it easier for others to show you how to generate the code via the macro language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use [`IN` operator](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n17vpypuojeg9zn1psc26z2ymju5.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) in `where` clause instead of equal(=). It works with list of vars.

```
%macro create_table(TableFields=,TimeS=);
...
WHERE TIME_S IN (%sysfunc(tranwrd(&TimeS,%str( ),%str(,))));/*replace space with comma*/
%mend create_table;

%create_table(TableFields=id,TimeS=39 51 63);
```

Comment: Unless you're writing a pass-through query with proc SQL and the remote database requires it, you don't need to replace spaces with commas.